# Vertical positioning of "part"-level header

Tags: sectioning, vertical-alignment, parts

I am using the \part sectioning with the following definition:

```
\def\@part[#1]#2{% <------------------------------- \part[..]{...}
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
       \huge {\scshape\partname\nobreakspace\thepart}% Part font
       \par\nobreak
     \fi
     \huge \bfseries #2% Title font
     \markboth{}{}\par}%
    \nobreak
    \vskip 3ex
    \@afterheading}
\def\@spart#1{% <------------------------------- \part*{...}
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \huge \bfseries #1\par}% Title font
     \nobreak
     \vskip 3ex
     \@afterheading}
```

Right now it is vertically centered on the page it creates.

How can I change the settings, to that the text of "Part X" appears more in the top of the page?

Comment: Which document class do you use? Please also clarify what you intend by "appears more [at] the top of the page" -- do you want it the very top edge, 1 cm down from the top edge, or something else? Please be specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using either the `report` or `book` document class, or a document class that's built on one of these classes, insert the following instructions in the preamble of your document to have the part-level header be placed close to the top edge of the text block:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\part}{\vfil}{}{}{}
```

To have the part-level header be placed smack dab *at the very top edge* of the text block, replace `\vfil` with `\null\vfil` in the second line of code above.